# For which prime $p$ are the additive groups $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-modules?

Tags: ring-theory, prime-numbers, modules, finite-fields

Homework for my algebra class. Chapter 14, Exercise 7.8 in Artin's Algebra, Second Edition:

> Let $F = \mathbb{F}_p$. For which
>   prime integers $p$ does the additive
>   group $F^1$ have a structure of a
>   $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module? How about
>   $F^2$?

I am submitting my possible solution as an answer; but I'm not sure if it's correct. Can I get a second opinion? Thank you.

P.S. If one of the regulars could tell me if questions like these are allowed (checking solutions), or how best to ask these kinds of questions, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, as discussed in the comments.

**Claim.** An abelian group $A$ has a structure as a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ module if and only if there exists $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ such that $\phi^2(a) = -a$ for all $a\in A$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $A$ has a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure. Define $\phi\colon A\to A$ by $\phi(a) = i\cdot a$. Then $\phi(a+b) = i\cdot(a+b) = (i\cdot a)+(i\cdot b) = \phi(a)+\phi(b)$, so $\phi$ is an endomorphism. Since $\phi^4(a) = a$ for all $a\in A$, it follows that $\phi$ is invertible as well, hence an automorphism. Also, $\phi^2(a) = i\cdot(i\cdot a) = (ii)\cdot a = (-1)\cdot a = -a$. Thus, if $A$ has a structure as a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module, then there exists $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ such that $\phi^2(a)=-a$.

Conversely, suppose there exists $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ such that $\phi^2(a)=-a$ for all $a\in A$. Define the action by $(r+si)\cdot a = (r+s\phi)(a) = ra+s\phi(a)$. which is easily verified to be a module structure. **QED**

From this it easily follows that if $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$, then we can make $\mathbb{F}_p$ into a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ module by considering the automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p$ (as an abelian group) given by multiplication by $\alpha$, where $\alpha^2 = -1$. It also shows, via your argument, that $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ module, by considering $\phi(a,b) = (-b,a)$.

You still have to show the necessity for $\mathbb{F}_p$, though.

**Hint:** See what $i\cdot 1$ is.

Comment: Here's my thought: let $\phi(x) = i \cdot x$, which is an automorphism as described in your proof. If $\phi(1) = i \cdot 1 = n$, for some $n \in \mathbb{F}$, then $\phi(n) = n\phi(1) = n^2$. Therefore $\phi^2(1) = n^2 = -1$, so $n = \phi(1)$ must be a square root of $-1$.

Comment: To show sufficient, as in your comment on my answer, let $\alpha$ be the element such that $\alpha^2 = -1$. Then define the action $(a+bi)\cdot x = (a+b\alpha)x$, and show that this defines a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module.

Comment: @Michael: (i) Yes, exactly! That shows the *necessity* of the existence of a square root of $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for the action to be defined. (ii) Yes, because if you have a field $\mathbf{F}$, and $\alpha\neq 0$, then the map $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is an abelian group automorphism of the additive group of $\mathbf{F}$. You can also see where the necessity breaks down for $\mathbb{F}_p^2$: for fields of prime order, *every* additive automorphism is of this form (because the additive group is cyclic), but not for fields of order $p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $F = \mathbb{F}_p$ to be a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module, the scalar multiplication by elements of the form $a + 0i$ is well defined. This leaves the element $i$. For $i$, note that there must be some action such that for all $a \in F$, $-a = i^2 \cdot a = i \cdot ( i \cdot a)$. Therefore $F$ must have an element whose square is $-1$. This is true precisely where $x^2+1$ is reducible, i.e. when $\mathbb{Z}/(p,x^2+1) = \mathbb{Z}[i]/p$ is not a field. So $F$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module precisely when $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (equivalent to when $p$ is not a Gaussian prime, and also equivalent to when $p \equiv 1$ modulo 4).

For $F^2 = {\mathbb{F}_p}^2$, use the notation for elements $(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are in $F$. Again, only need to find an action of $i$ such that $i^2 \cdot (a,b) = (-a,-b)$. Let $i \cdot (a,b) = (-b,a)$. This fulfills the necessary condition. So $F^2$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module for all $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "Gaussian prime" in the first part? $p$ is a rational prime here, not a prime in Z[i].

Comment: @alon the rational primes fall into two classes: those that split and those that stay prime ($p=2=(1+i)(1-i)$ and $p\equiv 4k+1=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ split, $p\equiv 4k+3$ are still prime)

Comment: Your first paragraph is somewhat muddled. For one thing, you are arguing that if there is a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure, *then* there must be an element whose square is $-1$, and immediately conclude that the latter conditions is necessary *and sufficient*; but you did not prove sufficiency. For another, it's not immediately clear to me how you derived the necessity. True, $ia$ must be an element of $F$ such that $i(ia)=-a$, but you have not shown that the action of $i$ must be equal to multiplication by some element of $F$. It could just be some permutation, perhaps?

Comment: @Alon: I've clarified the condition.

Comment: @Arturo: You are right, and I am trying to think of how to make the first part airtight. Having $p \equiv 1$ modulo 4 is sufficient, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @Michael: Indeed: *if* there is an element $\alpha$ whose square is $-1$, then you can turn it into a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ module by defining $(a+bi)\cdot x = (a+b\alpha)x$ and verifying this turns it into a module. But you need to say so explicitly. For necessity, you need to show that there is no automorphism of the abelian group whose square is equal to multiplication by $-1$.